# How to prove these algebras are subdirectly irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, universal-algebra

During lectures, we got to show that $C_9$, $C_9 + 1$ are subdirectly irreducible, where

**$C_n$** := $(\{0, 1, . . . , n − 1\}, (0  1 . . . n − 1))$

**$C_n + 1$** := $(\{0, 1, . . . , n − 1, n\}, (0    1 . . . n − 1)(n))$

I know the usual definition of subdirect irreducibility - An algebra $A$ is subdirectly irreducible, iff for every subdirect embedding $\alpha$, there is a projection such that: $\pi_i \circ \alpha: A \rightarrow A$ is an isomorphism.

Another definition is that

An algebra is subdirectly irreducible iff the intersection of all non-trivial congruences of he algebra is also non-trivial.

However, I don´t know how to even start with proving the exercise. Sorry that I dont show any of my progress, I just struggle with even the beginning.

How would you prove that they are subdirectly irreducible and which definition would you use?

Comment: I assume that the underlying set of $C_9$ is the same as the $9$-element cyclic group, and that the only operation of $C_9$ is $f(x)=x+1\pmod{9}$. Let $\theta$ be a congruence and let $X=0/\theta$ be the $\theta$-class of $0$. Show that $a, b\in X$ implies $a-b\in X$, so $X$ is the underlying set of a subgroup of $C_9$. Conclude that if $\theta$ is any nonzero congruence, then $(0,3)\in\theta$, establishing that your second definition is satisfied.

Comment: @KeithKearnes Thank you very much. I only did the simplest examples, so to be honest, this is still to difficult to me, but will go through your comment. Im strating to think I am unable to start, because there was no further description of the $C_9$ and I dont know if you description is correct. In your comment, how is "$(0,3) \in \theta$" establishing that intersection of nontrivial congruences is nontrivial?

Comment: If $(0,3)$ belongs to each nonzero congruence $\theta$, it belongs to the intersection of all nonzero congruences. Therefore, the intersection of nonzero congruences is nonzero.

Comment: @KeithKearnes I tried to put my thoughts into an answer, I think my process is different than what you suggested, maybe because I didnt describe the algebras the best way. However, I would be of course happy for another answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there has been no answer, I try my best to provide at least partial answer to my own question. I will be grateful if you add your comments or use my answer to write your own.

I am applying the \textit{Theorem 8.4} from Burris & Sankappanavar: An algebra $A$ is subdirectly irreducible iff $A$ is trivial or there is a minimum congruence in $Con A − \{\Delta\}$. In the latter case the minimum element is $\cap(Con A - \{\Delta\})$,
a principal congruence, and the congruence lattice of $A$ looks like the diagram below.

[image]

The $\Delta$ denotes "diagonal congruence relation" - the congruence relation that looks like this: "$|a|b|c|d|e|f|...$" and each element is related with itself. I will use $\Delta$ for denoting such relation.

For each algebra, I will first describe their elements and operations, then find non-trivial congruence relations on them.

Then I will try to find a \textit{monolith} for each of these algebras, since an algebra is subdirectly irreducible if and only if the lattice of its congruence relations has monolith.

(A monolith $\alpha$ is a congruence of an algebra $A$ such that for any congruence $\theta \in ConA\setminus \{\Delta\}$: $\alpha \leq \theta$.)

---

**Congruence relations on $C_9$**
[image]

$\Delta$ = $|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|$.

Other relations:

I start by generating congruence relations from $0$ paired with other elements.

It is clear that $0 \theta a$ implies $1 = f(0) \theta f(a) = a + 1$ for any $a \in C_9$. Since there is odd number of elements in this algebra.

From this and the algebra operation, it is intuitive that if I try to generate a congruence relation using $0$ and $1$ or any other pair $(a, a+1)$, the cycle will eventually get me "back to the start" and all elements end up related together.

Hence, one congruence relation is of course $|012345678|$.

Then, if I try to generate anything by relating $(a, a+2)$ or $(a, a+4)$ elements, I will end up with the same congruence relation.

Therefore, I try to generate different congruence relation by $(a, a+3)$.

Assume $0 \theta 3$ for some $\theta$. This will give $1 \theta 4 \implies 2 \theta 5 \implies 3 \theta 6 \implies 4 \theta 7 \implies 5 \theta 8 \implies 6 \theta 0$. Hence, we have another congruence relation: $|036|147|258|$.

Using $(a, a+6)$ as a pair of generators will also bring this congruence relation.

Using $(a, a+7)$ or $(a, a+8)$ will again generate a congruence relation that is already listed above.

**Finding the monolith**

In conclusion, the (non-diagonal) congruence relations on $C_9$ are $|036147258|$ and $|036|147|258|$.

**NOT SURE ABOUT THIS PART:**

*The $|036|147|258|$ is a monolith of the $C_9$, because if any $a \alpha b$ and $a \neq b$, $\alpha$ is an arbitrary congruence relation on $C_9$, then it follows that $0 \alpha 3 \alpha 6$.*

Hence, the $C_9$ is subdirectly irreducible.

---

**Congruence relations on $C_9+1$**
[image]

$\Delta$ = $|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|$.

Other relations:

Similarly to the previous case, there is the congruence relation relating all elements - $|0123456789|$.

Then, what is different about $C_9 + 1$ from the previous case is the $9$ that is mapped to itself.

This immediately brings that there will be one class where the $9$ is isolated and the rest forms the congruence relation from the previous case with $C_9$. So we have $|012345678|9|$.

By similar thinking, there is also the congruence relation $|036|147|258|9|$.

Then, if I try to use the $9$ as a generator for another congruence, I fail, since for any $a \theta 9$, it would have to follow that $a + 1 \theta 9, a + 2 \theta 9... a + 8 \theta 9$. This will of course create the congruence relation $|0123456789|$ and nothing new. So we run out of all possibilities.

**Finding the monolith**

In conclusion, apart from the diagonal congruence relation, there are $|0123456789|$, $|012345678|9|$ and $|036|147|258|9|$.

**NOT SURE ABOUT THIS PART:**

*The monolith is $|036|147|258|9|$, because it is contained in each of the other congruence relations. E.g. if $a \theta b$ for any $a \neq b$, then $0 \theta 3 \theta 6$.

So the $C_9 + 1$ is also subdirectly irreducible.

Comment: The partition $|036|147|258|$ corresponds to a nontrivial proper congruence of $C_9$. Similarly, $|036|147|258|9|$ corresponds to a nontrivial proper congruence of $C_9+1$.

Comment: In order to find non-trivial congruences, I'd suggest you to start by principal congruences. For example, taking after Keith Kearnes' comment: if $0\equiv3$ then $1=f(0)\equiv f(3)=4$; proceed until you run out of possibilities (until all pairs thus generated are repeated) and you'll have found $\theta(0,3)$. Do so for other pairs. After a while you'll do this much faster.

Comment: @amrsa Made edits here too, but still not sure how to show the monolith part for these algebras with "cycle" operation. Maybe using somehow modular arithmetic? Since here, I need to show not just two elements are related in each congruence relation, but three (e.g. $0, 3,6$)

Comment: In $C_9$, the monolith is $\theta(0,3)=\theta(3,6)=\cdots$ the one which you identified because from, for example $0\equiv3$ (or $a\equiv b$ for any $a\neq b$ in the same class that you identified) you can conclude the other congruences between elements, applying $f$ enough times: $$0\equiv3 \Rightarrow 1\equiv4 \Rightarrow 2\equiv5 \Rightarrow 3\equiv6\cdots.$$ On the other hand, from $0\equiv4$ you obtain $x\equiv y$ for all $x,y$, that is, ${\equiv}={\nabla}$. Similar for $C_9+1$.